# Entity Framework Core: internal exception when connecting to database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am running .NET 6.0.15 (SDK 6.0.407) and Entity Framework Core 6.0.15, trying to connect to a local SQL Server database on port 1433.

However, every time I attempt to access the DB I get the following error:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
Entity Framework Core 6.0.15 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.15' with options: None
```

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'virtualcampusdb' on server 'sqlserver'.
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'VirtualCampusAPI.Data.DataContext'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
>
> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000001, 11): Resource temporarily unavailable

This is my connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=virtualcampusdb;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=sa;Password=YourStrongPassw0rd;"
```

The database is up and running and I can query it normally using a client like DataGrip. It seems the issue is related to some .NET configuration.

Note: This all started when I attempted to update my local .NET versions to match the ones in the project's docker container. Before, the containerized app ran normally and could connect to the database. After my update attempt the docker project started to throw the same error.

Any help?

Comment: did you need a proxy? In any case I would not suggest use the "sa" user. This could be a question for [dba.se]

Comment: Using a trusted connected & passing SQL authentication details doesn't make sense; it's one or the other you can't have both.

Comment: Are you getting this error inside the Docker container? From a networking perspective Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs, so with `localhost` resolving to `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) or `::1` (IPv6) the `Server=localhost,1433;` connection parameter is telling EF to connect to an SQL Server instance running inside the Docker container itself. If you're wanting to connect to a port on the Docker host then have you tried `Server=host.docker.internal,1433;` instead?